# F key reformatting document instead of writing 'f'

Tags: eclipse

I have an annoying problem with Eclipse 3.8 on Ubuntu, whenever I press the f key, it reformats the document, as if I'm pressing <kbd>ctrl-shift-f</kbd>.

Other programs are not affected, only eclipse, even after a reboot.

Any ideas on which settings i can delete / alter?

Comment: This happens only in PHP editor mode. Also under the Source -> Format menu item the shortcut key is actually displayed as just 'F'!

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the shortcut key format from preferences: `Preferences -> General -> Keys`

[image]

Comment: Removing the shortcut should get you past the problem and allow you to program... if that works, see if "f" prints for you after that.

Comment: I found the format binding for the PHP editor and removed it, but no change im afraid

Comment: Tried removing the .metadata directory which didn't work either.

Comment: @nfvindaloo, did you remove all of the bindings?